# MSVC 2015 SFINAE Failing To Find Proper Member Function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Using MSVC 2015, I have some basic code as follows:

```
class Setter {
public:
    void set(int value) {}
    template <int Size> void set(int value[Size]) {}
};
```

It doesn't seem to matter what the setters do, so I left them blank.  However, if I attempt to use the array version of `set` as follows:

```
int data[128];
Setter setter;
setter.set(data);
```

I receive the following compile-time error:

```
error C2664 : 'void Setter::set(int)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int [128]' to 'int'
```

According to the rules of SFINAE, shouldn't there exist a member function whose signature matches exactly to the `Setter` class?  The template `set`, it seems, should match to something along the lines of `template<> void Setter::set(int value[128]) {}` which can be deduced.  Is there some rule that prohibits this code from compiling in the standard, or is MSVC doing something wrong?  Thanks!

**EDIT**

Really, I need a solution here.  So if someone can't point me to an answer in the standard but knows a work around, I'm very receptive to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
 template <int Size> void set(int (&value)[Size]) {}
```

You can't pass a simple int array by value, you should do it like that (by ref).

If you want to pass an array by value, consider using std::array